# How to convert a specific part of materialize.scss to css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want only a portion of Materalize css. Like only the css related to buttons.
For that materialize css has provided with sass.But the problem is when i try to convert a partial scss to css I get all kinds of errors.Only thing that is converted without error is the whole materialize file. Is there any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialize scss files are interrelated with each other. Means you cannot comment mixins, colors, variables and if you do so you will get errors.

For all the other elements under //components comment you can comment then as per your need.[image: Here is a sample.]

Comment: nope did not work I got `Error: ".btn" failed to @extend ".z-depth-1".
       The selector ".z-depth-1" was not found.
       Use "@extend .z-depth-1 !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 58 of components/_buttons.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.`

Comment: ok didnt work exactly just for buttons but added a few other components and now it works

Comment: hi sorry, couldn't response you quick , yes it should work , maybe buttons are connected to other components as well. search for .z-depth-1 and uncomment the following component.